# Convert responsive web page to PDF

Tags: browser, web, adobe-acrobat

Couldn't decide if this is a question better for Stack Overflow or Superuser, but I'll start here.

I have Adobe Acrobat 9.0 Pro, and with that, the Convert Web Page to PDF button that displays in IE. We use this at work to review web pages and comment/markup for changes, etc.

When I use it on a web page that is responsive (such as http://microsoft.com) the resulting PDF shows the page laid out as if the browser window was sized down, but then it stretches all the elements to fit the width of the PDF.

Does anyone know if this is because of the rendering engine the Convert button uses? The resulting PDF looks a bit similar to how the page would look in Quirks mode in IE9 (using F12 developer tools and choosing Quirks mode from the Document Mode drop down.) Thanks for any help!

Comment: What version of Adobe Acrobat exactly.  You also have to explain you believe "Quirks Mode" in IE is exactly.  Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Thanks, updated the question. I don't have the Convert Web Pages button for other browsers than IE.

Comment: @wylander: Can't you use something else instead, such as a PDF printer like Bullzip?